# How to create a new core in Solr using API and copying configuration from a configSet

Tags: solr

I am trying to create a new core based in a configSet.

I do properly using command line:

```
./solr create -c new_core -d my_configset
```

It create a new core, **copying the configuration** from my_configset.
That's the log:

```
Copying configuration to new core instance directory:
/Users/sergio/Desarrollo/tools/solr/solr-5.5.0/server/solr/test

Creating new core 'test' using command:
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=test&instanceDir=test

{
"responseHeader":{
"status":0,
"QTime":178},
"core":"test"}
```

I am trying to do the same with the API, it does not work.

I am using the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=test&configSet=data_driven_schema_with_json_embedded_support_configs
```

But it does not copy the configuration from the configset, instead of that, it links the configset with the new core, and the configset is shared among the cores than use the same configset. Any change in the schema is shared among the cores.

Is there any possibility to have the same behaviour that one with the command line?

Comment: I am having the same issue:

 
how can we copy all the required directores (like config, lang) to the new core directory?? becuase when we just hit to the above CREATE action, then it just ask to copy all the required directories first in which we will have our solrconfig.xml

Comment: As I say in my question, you can do it with the command: 

./solr create -c new_core -d my_configset

I am still don't know how to make it with HTTP API Schema.

Comment: I am having requirment, where i need to create multiple cores on runtime, so I dont want to run any command, i just want a way through which i can create a core and index some documents in that  speicific core.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running **SOLR in cloud mode** you can do the following steps I've given below.

**For Solr Standalone mode:**

For SOLR sandalone mode you will have to make copy of the default configset folder and then use the name of the new folder as your configuraiton -- the API  configset copy feature is not not avilable on the standalone mode.

**For SolrCloud mode:**

1. Create a new configset for your table
2. Create your table using the new configset that you just created

`http://ip:port/solr/admin/configs?action=CREATE&name=<my_config_set_name>&baseConfigSet=_default`

Change the string `<my_config_set_name>` and the `ip:port` in the URL above.

Now when you create your table you can use the newlycreated configset which will be unique and dedicated to this table only.